# Почему отказывается работать laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Ошибку можно наблюдать здесь testsitefortest.ru
На хостинге + локалке работала отлично, стоило загрузить на сервер с centos 7 начались проблемы

Подскажите, пожалуйста как решить проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А версии PHP на локальном сервере и на боевом отличаются?

Могу, конечно, ошибаться, но возможно дело в PHP v8.1 - по крайней мере схожие проблемы отталкиваются от этого момента.

Comment: на локалке стоит 8.0, на сервере 8.1, а на хостинге стояла 8.0, но здесь разница между версиями минимальная, точно не смотрел что изменилось, но разве может быть в этом проблема ?

Comment: Не уверен точно, но возможно проблема именно в версиях. Если мельком посмотреть первую страницу выдачи по данной ошибке и Laravel - то несколько людей ссылаются на ошибки именно при версии PHP 8.1.

Так или иначе, попробуйте на сервере откатиться до 8.0.

Comment: Большое спасибо, пол дня потратил в попытках разобраться) но вот на версию php даже не думал, попробую. Спасибо